# Setting Cell Text Color

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Apparently this is deprecated :

```
cell.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Does anyone know what the best way to change the color of a Cell Text ?

---

Edit after comment :

I'm now using this :

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

but the color is still not changing, see the IB parameters :

[image]

Comment: do you use cell that created in IB or just instantiated via cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Comment: Not erroring out anymore thanks, but the text color is still not changing for some reason .. ( see the edit )

Answer (score 2):

Like says Apple on the UITableViewCell page http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> The color of the title text. (Deprecated in iOS 3.0. Instead set the text color attribute of   the UILabel objects assigned to the textLabel and detailTextLabel properties.)

You must use the textLabel instead textColor ;-)

Edit : you must add your OWN textLabel.
You must forget cell.text